# Page transition with a preloader

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been searching all over and can not seem to find a good tutorial on how to transition pages when clicking a link on my site. I would like the the ability for when I click a link it fades the page and displays a preloaded. Once the preloaded is completed a new page will fade in. Here is an example of what I am talking about http://www.admirhadzic.com

Any help would be great.

**Preloader**

```
 <div id="preloader">
     <div id="status">&nbsp;</div>
 </div>
```

**Script**

```
    $(window).load(function() { // makes sure the whole site is loaded
        $("#status").fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation
        $("#preloader").delay(350).fadeOut("slow"); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.
    })
```

**css**

```
 #preloader {
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        bottom:0;
        background-color:#fff; /* change if the mask should have another color then white */
        z-index:99; /* makes sure it stays on top */
 }

 #status {
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        position:absolute;
        left:50%; /* centers the loading animation horizontally one the screen */
         top:50%; /* centers the loading animation vertically one the screen */
         background-image:url(../img/status.gif); /* path to your loading animation */
         background-repeat:no-repeat;
         background-position:center;
         margin:-100px 0 0 -100px; /* is width and height divided by two */
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried to use preloader before?

Comment: Yes I have tried one before @AdrianEnriquez I can get one to work properly but I do not know how to transition from page to page without showing the white flash

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: I just added what I have so far to my question above @AdrianEnriquez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site cited in your example, http://www.admirhadzic.com/, appears to be using an AngularJS or similar framework. Namely, the site is contained on a single page, so you never get the "white flash" (mentioned in the comments) from navigating to another page.

Without changing the framework of your application, you can use an ajax request to asynchronously grab the new page content. On success, the ajax method could replace the content of your page and do exactly what you're currently doing in your `$(window).onload()` function.

For example:

```
function LinkClick(){

  // load the waiting image and back-drop
  $("#preloader").fadeIn();
  $("#status").fadeIn();

  // kick off the ajax request for the new content
  $("#div-to-be-replaced").load("ajax/page-you-want-to-show.html", function(){
    $("#status").fadeOut();
    $("#preloader").fadeOut;
  });
}
```

You could do the same thing with jQuery.ajax() and probably a number of other functions. See http://api.jquery.com/load/ and http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.

Comment: how would I go about doing this with the code I already have? @Kjata30

Comment: Tough to get any more specific without actually seeing your code, but the example I posted should get you moving in the right direction.

Comment: I am sorry I do not have that much to show you. I have been looking around to find a solution to what I am looking for. I will take a look at your code. Thank you @Kjata30

Comment: what would you recommend to load all pages instead of just a single html page @Kjata30

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "load all pages." The whole point of using or developing a framework like Angular is to load all of the content you need on a single page. You can use this to load multiple "pages" without sending an additional http request by using jQuery.load or some other asynchronous JavaScript method.